# What is meant by AF?

Tags: routing, router

For example, *route* manual says:

> route {-h|--help} [] Detailed usage syntax for specified AF.

What is meant by AF ? I tried to google the term but no success (found only something about an *af-interface* for Cisco routers).

Comment: I think we need more context. For example, in QoS, AF means Assured Forwarding, which is a classification for packets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AF in this case is short for *address family*, ie. IPv4 or IPv6.